# Mathematical operation in two base fields

Tags: jquery

I tried this code to multiple. The scenario should be

1. if textbox 2 is empty the textbox 1 will multiply in rate
2. if textbox 1 is empty textbox2 will multiple to rate.

Scenario 1 works perfectly, but the scenario 2 is not.. any help?

```
<script src="../../plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<label>1</label><input type="text" id="quantitytotransferw"/><br><br>
<label>2</label><input type="text" id="quantitytotransfer"/><br><br>
<label>rate</label><input type="text" id="rate"/><br><br>
<label>amount</label><input type="text" id="amount"/><br><br>

</body>
</html>
<script>
 $('#rate').keyup(function(){
        var textone;
        var texttwo;
        textone = parseFloat($('#quantitytotransferw').val());
        texttwo = parseFloat($('#rate').val());
        var result = textone * texttwo;
        $('#amount').val(result.toFixed(2));
    });
     $('#rate').keyup(function(){
        var textone;
        var texttwo;
        textone = parseFloat($('#quantitytotransferw').val());
        texttwo = parseFloat($('#rate').val());
        var result = textone * texttwo;
        $('#amount').val(result.toFixed(2));
    });

       $('#quantitytotransferw').keyup(function(){
        var textone;
        var texttwo;
        textone = parseFloat($('#quantitytotransferw').val());
        texttwo = parseFloat($('#rate').val());
        var result = textone * texttwo;
        $('#amount').val(result.toFixed(2));


    }); 
           $('#quantitytotransfer').keyup(function(){
        var textone;
        var texttwo;
        textone = parseFloat($('#quantitytotransfer').val());
        texttwo = parseFloat($('#rate').val());
        var result = textone * texttwo;
        $('#amount').val(result.toFixed(2));


    }); 

                  </script>
```

Comment: where is logic to see if the textbox is empty or not?

Comment: i dont have that because i based on input

Comment: ...and why do you have 2 identical click handlers on `#rate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this function, which combines all you had:

```
$('#rate, #quantitytotransferw, #quantitytotransfer').on('input', function(){
    var qty = +$('#quantitytotransferw').val();
    qty = qty || +$('#quantitytotransfer').val();
    var rate = +$('#rate').val();
    var result = qty * rate;
    $('#amount').val(result.toFixed(2));
});
```

```js
$('#rate, #quantitytotransferw, #quantitytotransfer').on('input', function(){
    var qty = +$('#quantitytotransferw').val();
    qty = qty || +$('#quantitytotransfer').val();
    var rate = +$('#rate').val();
    var result = qty * rate;
    $('#amount').val(result.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>1</label><input type="text" id="quantitytotransferw"/><br><br>
<label>2</label><input type="text" id="quantitytotransfer"/><br><br>
<label>rate</label><input type="text" id="rate"/><br><br>
<label>amount</label><input type="text" id="amount"/>
```

Some remarks:

- You have a lot of repetitive code. Code is more maintainable if you write code only once and *call* that where needed.
- The `keyup` event does not trigger on all possible ways to alter input data. Take for example, a copy/paste action via the context menu. The `input` event will trigger on any change (in modern browsers).
- You can use unitary `+` for conversion of string to number
- `textone` is not really a good name for something that is number and not text. Try to give variables meaningful names.
- You need to check whether the first input is empty or not. I have now tested that the conversion to number is 0, which may or may not be exactly what you want. Anyway, an empty string or 0 in the first input will make the formula take the value of the second input (by using the `||` operator).